# How do you solve an equation that has one variable term on one side and constant terms on the other side?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, how can it be possible to solve $4+6=2y$?  I think I know two ways to do it: $$4+6=2y$$$$4+6-4=2y-4$$$$6=2y-4$$$$6+4=2y-4+4$$$$10=2y$$$${10\over 2}={2y\over 2}$$$$5=y$$and$$4+6=2y$$$$10=2y$$$${10\over 2}={2y\over 2}$$$$5=y$$See?  I get the same answer!  Is this how to do it?  Tell me what you think and be sure to answer the question.

Comment: I definitely prefer the second "way", because I allways recommend to simplify both sides of an equation first until you move things from one side to the other. But thats just my way to do it.

Comment: I know a third way: $$4+6=2y$$$${4+6\over 2}={2y\over 2}$$$$2+3=y$$$$5=y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost always combine constants when you can.  Sometimes, like when completing a square, you might have separate constants on the same side of an equality, but generally, combine up all your constants as soon as you can.